# Error: "package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’" when installing devtools

Tags: r, installation, devtools

Devtools is failing to install. When I run the function:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

R tells me the package is successfully unpacked. But when I run `library(devtools)` - I get an error message (see below).

Full console:

```
`>install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/fallo/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/devtools_2.2.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 351954 bytes (343 KB)
downloaded 343 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\fallo\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2Ddudk\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
  error: namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required`> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/fallo/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/devtools_2.2.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 351954 bytes (343 KB)
downloaded 343 KB

package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\fallo\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2Ddudk\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
  error: namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is required
```

Comment: Go to `session`on top in RStudio then `Restart R` or `Ctrl+Shift+F10` or close and reopen RStudio

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what causes this particular problem, but in my case it happenned when I installed Rtools to install some packages. Eventually, it started to give the same error with many packages. Removing R completely and reinstalling it back solved my problem.